# gitattributes and line endings confusion

Tags: git

From:
http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_using_attribute_macros

> **End-of-line conversion**
>
> While Git normally leaves file contents alone, it can be configured to normalize line endings to LF in the repository and, optionally, to convert them to CRLF when files are checked out.
>
> Here is an example that will make Git normalize .txt, .vcproj and .sh files, ensure that .vcproj files have CRLF and .sh files have LF in the working directory, and prevent .jpg files from being normalized regardless of their content.
>
> ```
> *.txt       text
> *.vcproj    eol=crlf
> *.sh        eol=lf
> *.jpg       -text
> ```

What is the difference between:

```
*   text
*   eol=crlf
```

I my repo I have tried to add:

```
*.txt       text
*.sample    eol=crlf
```

But it gives the same (Both have CRLF line endings) so are those attributes equivalent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  These produce the same output *if and only if your platform uses CR/LF natively*.

The `text` instruction tells Git to use whatever line endings are standard for your platform.

If you checked these files out on a Unix system (which uses LF only) then your `.sample` files would be checked out with CR/LF line endings, and your `.txt` files would be checked out with LF line endings.

Comment: Its seems the meaning of "text" and "-text" is not the same. As I understand "text" converts to LF and "-text" does nothing. Anywhere the difference between these two options are described?